# How to get Entity Registration fields into a View

Tags: views, users

I need help understanding if this is even possible or not. I have a view where we search current users within the site. I want to see if I can add parts of the Registration Module into the view so when we find someone that went to the event but didn't sign up online we can add them to the event post-event for reporting. I know I can just copy their user name then navigate to the registration page and add them, however I want to see if I can better the process by allowing the Content Admin the ability to register them from the view directly.

See attached for helpful image. Any ideas will be helpful since I am not a hard core php/drupal developer.

[image]

Comment: Presumably Entity Registration defines fieldable entities (never used it)? If so you might get some mileage out of [Editable views](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews)

Comment: Do you think that I would be able to bring in the submit or register button that saves it? or would that be a code thing?

Comment: You'll get a submit button that saves changes to all the entities in the table by default...just don't show too many on one page or hitting that button can exhaust your memory

Comment: @Clive Thank you I got the States to show and I see the save button. Another Question that arose...when I filter on last name name it doesn't just show me the user but all the events the user has registered for, so I can not register them for that event. I am trying to just get the user so I can register just that user. Any thoughts as to why that happens?

The view is just user, first, last, degree, specialty, username with a relationship to registration. 

Thanks again for your awesome help!!!